# some Gradle command-line options not working

Tags: gradle

I have the following code:

```
task helloGradle {
   println 'Hello Gradle - This is your first script'
}

task failedTask {
   assert 1 == 2
}

task test(dependsOn:helloGradle) {
   println 'Test case executed'
}
```

I expect the execution to fail and stop when gradle is executing the second task from the command line (Ubuntu), which it does. However, when I use the --continue option so that it goes on to execute the last task ('test') regardless of whether the execution of the second task failed, it still gets stuck on the failed task and goes no further.

The command I'm issuing on the command-line (from within my project directory) is as follows:

```
gradle failedTask test --continue
```

Even when I try other command-line options like:

```
gradle --gui
```

It doesn't launch the Gradle GUI as I expect and comes up with - Unknown command-line option '--gui'.

Am I doing something wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

According to [the official doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html), there are three phases in a Gradle build: **initialization**, **configuration**, and **execution**. Both your `println` and `assert` statements are in the configuration phase, not execution phase. That's why `--continue` did not work as what you expected.

You could check the sample code in the official doc:

```gradle
println 'This is executed during the configuration phase.'

tasks.register('configured') {
    println 'This is also executed during the configuration phase, because :configured is used in the build.'
}

tasks.register('test') {
    doLast {
        println 'This is executed during the execution phase.'
    }
}

tasks.register('testBoth') {
    doFirst {
        println 'This is executed first during the execution phase.'
    }
    doLast {
        println 'This is executed last during the execution phase.'
    }
    println 'This is executed during the configuration phase as well, because :testBoth is used in the build.'
}
```